# Timeout Exception from Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish

I am making a post request for a service in java. Example of request: `http://192.168.1.1:8080/MyService/my/service/execQueryJson/p`

When the size of `p` is small, it works. But if a `p` with a large number of parameters (for example, 180 KB), then Glassfish chops it off.

If I run a request from the browser, then the response is empty. If I run a request from SoapUI, I get `Error getting response; java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` after 20 seconds.

In the glassfish log there is an entry:

```
  StandardWrapperValve[com.git.service.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.git.service.ApplicationConfig threw exception
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read(TemporarySelectorReader.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read(TemporarySelectorReader.java:75)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.AbstractReader.read(AbstractReader.java:72)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleRead(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.TransportFilter.handleRead(TransportFilter.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.read(DefaultFilterChain.java:351)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.read(FilterChainContext.java:695)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.blockingRead(InputBuffer.java:1119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.io.ServerInputBuffer.blockingRead(ServerInputBuffer.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.fill(InputBuffer.java:1143)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:270)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream.read(EntityInputStream.java:101)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
```

Then another 60 lines of stacktrace.
This exception is thrown explicitly by glassfish, because the execution doesn't even reach the try-catch in my code.

Empirically, it was found that the request breaks when the size is more than 66869 bytes - what kind of magic number it is a mystery to me (Google did not give any results).

On the Internet, it is advised to increase the Selector Poll Timeout (server-config/Network Config/Transport/tcp) - I increased the Selector Poll Timeout (from 1 s to 15) and Read Timeout (from 30 s to 60), it did not help. What else to fix, I do not know. Any specific ideas?

Glassfish version is 4.1 (not 3.x).

Comment: Could you provide us with some code. plz.

Comment: Code of request? `http://192.168.1.1:8080/MyService/my/service/execQueryJson/p`